# About http post from desktop application

Tags: http, post

My q is whats can stop http post from desktop applications ?

e.g

i have a desktop application before it start it's ask users form some information
like a username ad Email ,,, and then take this information and post it on php webpage and php insert it into MySql Server any way the problem  now is lets say like

6 of 16 download(s) are registered and the others not so whats can make http post not run correctly ?

Note :
Software tested on every windows os and runs ok
Software run with all anti viruses programs ok
Software add port throw windows firewall ok

So whats can make http post not run correctly ?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many things that could stop communication between your application, and your database.

- If the client has a firewall that requires authorisation for outbound requests.
- If the client has to connect via a proxy server, and you application is not proxy aware
- If your website fails to process your request (perhaps, if the MySql server is too busy to allow connections, etc.)

So, consider an end user behind a [WebSense](http://www.websense.com/) proxy that additionally allows administrators to filter out unwanted traffic. If your application is not proxy server aware, it will fail to connect; If your application is proxy aware, and whatever WebSense category you fall into is filtered for that client, it will also fail to connect.